# Python 3.6 - Tkinter - Clipboard issues

Tags: python, tkinter, clipboard

I am trying to add copy/paste to my program, but it isn't working quite right.
I haven't really used Tkinter much before this, so I might not use the code effectively.

**My problem:**

If I copy something from, let's say, Wikipedia, and then try to paste it using the code below then it works fine. 

The copy-function also works fine, for the most part. 

The problem is that once I've used the copy function then it will no longer register anything else added outside the program.

If I use , for example, `r.clipboard_append("Hello"))`, and then try to copy something from Wikipedia, and then try to use the paste-function, it will just paste "Hello". 

But if I paste into a word document or something, then it will paste whatever I copied from Wikipedia.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#Copy
if click[0] == 1:
    print("Copy")

    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    temp = ""
    r.clipboard_clear()
    for i in range (len(Array)):
        temp = temp+Array[i][1]
    r.clipboard_append(str(temp))
    r.destroy()

#Paste
if click[0] == 1:
    try:
        print("Paste")
        r=Tk()
        r.withdraw()
        temp = ""
        result = r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
        r.destroy

        temp = str(result)
        for i in temp:
            Array.append([len(Array), i])
    except TclError:
        print("Value Error")
```

Comment: Humm, no way to reproduce your problem. All tests have been performed 1: copy from text file / paste to Python/tkinter, 2: copy from/ paste to Python/tkinter and 3: copy from Python/tkinter / paste to text editor... What kind of errors did you get (except `Array` errors) ?

Comment: I don't really get any errors. It's just that once something has been appended then it won't register a new entry unless I append it as well. Even if I CTRL+C something from a text-editor. 
The paste-function works fine untill I use the copy function. Though using the copy-function and pasting in text-editor afterwards works fine. It's just text-file to Python that stops working.